# Drupal 8 is there a way to show the filesize of an image in the media library?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, filesize

I need to optimize all the files being used on a Drupal 8 site, and I don't have admin privileges.  When I look at the Media Library, no file sizes are displayed.  Is there a way to see the size without downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

How I ended up doing it:

`/admin/content/files` displays file sizes. Filter for image and Sort by size. I clicked on `Used In` to get the name of the Media Entity Type using the image.  I then went and edited the Media Entity, replacing the old large image with my smaller optimized version.  The old large image, being unused, changed status to Temporary and was gone after 24 hours.